# RGBDSLAM_freiburg : 'node not found' on groovy

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed and built **rgbdslam_freiburg** as given in *http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam*. When I tried to execute the following command

*roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch*

I got the following error:

*ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rgbdslam/rgbdslam]: can't locate node [rgbdslam] in package [rgbdslam]*

'roscd' is able to locate the package rgbdslam. It is found inside my catkin workspace, where I downloaded the code from this link *http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg* given in the tutorial

However
***rosnode info rgbdslam***
returns
***cannot contact [/rgbdslam]: unknown node***

I'm running ros groovy on Ubuntu 12.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62405/rgbdslam_freiburg-:-%27node-not-found%27-on-groovy/) by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you compiled it? It's not a binary download. See the wiki page for how to do it.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leo pauly](https://answers.ros.org/users/11031/leo-pauly/) on 2014-01-20**:
compiled it. but still it shows same error..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-01-23**:
And compilation was successful, I assume. You have to find the binary then. Try searching in your workspace with "find -executable -name rgbdslam -type f".

**Comment by [Michiel](https://answers.ros.org/users/11396/michiel/) on 2014-01-29**:
I have the same problem. Compilation was succesful. Any update on this?

Also, I noticed that I can't use rosrun or roscd, altough I included "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" in my ~/.bashrc file. The other ros-commands are working.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-02-14**:
I have migrated rgbdslam to hydro. Let me know whether you would like to test a probably unstable release.

**Comment by [leo pauly](https://answers.ros.org/users/11031/leo-pauly/) on 2014-02-22**:
im running on ros hydro.but still the error continues

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-02-25**:
Leo: Please be specific. You are running what on ros hydro? The rgbdslam package from googlecode?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-02-25**:
Michiel:Have you created a workspace and sourced the respective setup.bash, so that rgbdslam is in your package path? Check with "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
@leo pauly @Michiel @Felix Endres Do you use catkin workspace or rosbuild one? The instruction uses a rosbuild ws. I am not sure which is correct to install this package on hydro.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-03-27**:
For fuerte I am using rosbuild. For the (yet unreleased) hydro version I use catkin